# PostgreSQL query breaks after adding xmlns attribute

Tags: postgresql, xpath, xml-namespaces

I have PostgreSQL query:

```
SELECT
     (xpath('//TypeCode/text()', myTempTable.myXmlColumn))[1]::text AS c1
    ,(xpath('//TypeName/text()', myTempTable.myXmlColumn))[1]::text AS c2
    ,(xpath('//BookDate/text()', myTempTable.myXmlColumn))[1]::text AS c3
    ,(xpath('//BankRef/text()', myTempTable.myXmlColumn))[1]::text AS c4
    ,(xpath('//AccAmt/text()', myTempTable.myXmlColumn))[1]::text AS c5
    ,myTempTable.myXmlColumn as myXmlElement
FROM 
  unnest(
    xpath(
      '/FIDAVISTA/Statement/AccountSet/CcyStmt/TrxSet',
      XMLPARSE(document (SELECT xml_data FROM bank_xml WHERE id = 1))
    )
  ) AS myTempTable(myXmlColumn)
;
```

It selects data from online banking XML with transaction data from table bank_xml field xml_data.
Everything works fine as long as there is no xmlns attribute present.
If we add

```
xmlns="http://ivis.eps.gov.lv/XMLSchemas/100017/fidavista/v1-2"
```

to root node query returns 0 records.

How to modify the query to ignore xmlns attribute in root node of XML?

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution to this which involves being explicit about the namespace in each XPath query.

You need to provide the `xpath` function with an array of namespace mappings. Each namespace mapping is an array whose first element is a namespace prefix such as e.g. `f`, and whose second element is the namespace URI (e.g. `http://ivis.eps.gov.lv/XMLSchemas/100017/fidavista/v1-2` in your case). See the documentation including examples here:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-xml.html#id-1.5.8.21.7.3.2

If you map the prefix `f` to that namespace URI, you can then change your XPath expressions so that the element names are all prefixed with `f:` and it should all work.

Comment: Can I provide empty mapping?
Because with out it (xmlns attribute) everything works.

Comment: No, I don't believe that Postgresql supports defining a "default namespace", i.e. using a blank namespace prefix, if that's what you mean, to imply that every unprefixed name in your XPath should be interpreted as having a particular namespace URI (as you can, for example, with the `xpath-default-namespace` attribute in XSLT <https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#unprefixed-qnames>). I think you have to be explicit, tedious as it is.

Comment: Ended up using regex to cut out that part, now everything works.